# Type of 'this' is inferred at build time but not at editing time

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

In the following TypeScript code, the type of `me` is properly inferred at build time and thus `me.text=num` induces the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

```
function foo(): void
{
    let x = {
        text: <string>null,
        setValue: function(num: number): void
        {
            let me = this;
            me.text = num; // expected to raise error
        }
    };
}
```

But at editing time, intellisense reports no error.

It happens in Visual Studio 2019.
Here is the tsconfig :

```
"compilerOptions":
{
    "target": "ES2015",
    "lib": [ "DOM", "ES6", "DOM.Iterable", "ScriptHost", "ES2017.String", "ES2018.AsyncIterable" ],
    "module": "none",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false
    ...
}
"typeAcquisition":
{
    "enable": false
    ...
}
```

Comment: [It works for me](https://tsplay.dev/mAdgQN), the type of `me` (and of `this`) in that function is the type of `x`, which is inferred from the object being assigned. What `tsconfig.json` settings are you using? (I did make one small change to your code because the default settings don't allow `<string>null`, but I'm guessing you're not using strict null checks.)

Comment: @t-j-crowder Thanks for your input. When I put `me.value=2;`, Visual Studio reports no error in the editor. And when I build the project, VS reports the error "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'" in the Error List, but still no error in the editor. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Visual Studio 2019. (I've never used Visual Studio to write TypeScript; Visual Studio Code is very good at it, though.)